# How to transform from SRID 4258 to 4326 in PostGIs

Tags: geospatial, postgis, srid

I have a column with polygons with the SRID 4258, I have been trying to transform that column to SRID 4326 but does not transform it correctly.

I have done using this two commands:

```
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('lig','geom',4326);
UPDATE lig SET geom=ST_TRANSFORM(ST_SETSRID(geom, 4258), 4326);
```

Any clues? I mean it should work!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using PostGIS 2.x, where you can directly specify the [ALTER TABLE DDL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) to change the definition of the table and update the column as required by ST_Transform:

```
ALTER TABLE lig
 ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Polygon, 4326)
   USING ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom, 4258), 4326);
```

If you are still using PostGIS 1.x, [follow some of these instructions to modify the geometry type](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/28878/1872).